# Stopping Windows 7 application to send ARP request?

Tags: sockets, networking, window, arp

I have an application which runs on Windows 7 and communicates with external hardware. Both the external hardware and Windows 7 uses static IPs to communicate.

**Issue:**
Sometimes ARP packets being sent by Windows 7 cause loss of packets being sent by hardware.

Is there any method to stop sending ARP requests by my system or is there a list of applications which uses the network so that I can disable them ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a static ARP entry to tie the external IP and MAC address together without the Windows 7 machine having to do ARP requests to resolve the MAC for that IP.

In a command line run,

```
netsh interface ipv4 add neighbors {external machine IP} {external machine MAC}
```